# sqlcipher ./configuration Windows

Tags: c++, c, qt, sqlite, sqlcipher

How can I compile Sqlcipher on windows?

I'm trying this:

- `Git Clone sqlcipher C:\sqlcipher`
- `Install MINGW32 C:\MINGW32`
- `Install msys C:\MINGW32\msys\1.0`
- `Install tcltk-8.4.1-1 C:\MINGW32\bin tclsh84 to tclsh.exe`
- `Install Win32OpenSSL-1_0_1f C:\OpenSSL-Win32`

1- Run `C:\MINGW32\msys\1.0\msys.exe`

2 - Cmd mysys command `cd c:sqlcipher`

3 - `./configure --prefix=C:/Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlcipher CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="-lcrypto"`

<s>returns the error:</s>

./configure: line 470: sed: command not found
./configure: line 469: expr:command not found
./configure: line 470: sed: command not found
./configure: line 484: sed: command not found

---

Updated

Config.log

```
configure:2484: checking build system type
configure:2498: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2518: checking host system type
configure:2531: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2599: checking for gcc
configure:2615: found /bin/gcc
configure:2626: result: gcc
configure:2855: checking for C compiler version
configure:2864: gcc --version >&5
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2875: $? = 0
configure:2864: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\gcc.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC) 
configure:2875: $? = 0
configure:2864: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2875: $? = 1
configure:2864: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2875: $? = 1
configure:2895: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2917: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
configure:2921: $? = 1
configure:2959: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "sqlcipher"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "sqlcipher"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.8.0.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "sqlcipher 3.8.0.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2964: error: in `/c/sqlcipher':
configure:2966: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: You need more than just mingw. You need a full gnu environment, so install something like msysgit.

Comment: msysgit do not have GCC, CC, CL.

Comment: Have you even tried? Git bash will have all the necessary tools, although I have no any idea what you mean by CC or CL in a gnu environment...

Comment: I've tried yes, but returns the missing dependency on package. I'm downloading gcc-core to test.